# node js 's Buffer.toString( 'binary')

Tags: node.js, express, buffer, encode

although Buffer's 'binary'  is deprecated,  I have to use it:
I write a web app use node js +express.  user can download file, and filename will Garbled if not use

```
 res.download(allpath,buf0.toString('binary'));
```

watch the value (is a chinese char):

```
console.log(new Buffer('牛'));
```

output: Buffer,e7,89,9b

and

```
var buf0=new Buffer('牛');
console.log(new Buffer(buf0.toString('binary')));
```

output: Buffer,c3,a7,c2,89,c2,9b

what meaning this algorithm,and why use binary toString is work?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `new Buffer('牛')` is a shortcut for `new Buffer('牛', 'utf-8')`.
Thus if you want to convert it back to a string you have to use `toString('utf-8')`.

Example:

```
console.log(new Buffer('牛'));
// Output: <Buffer e7 89 9b>

var buf0=new Buffer('牛');
console.log(new Buffer(buf0.toString('utf-8')));
// Output: <Buffer e7 89 9b>
```

Further reading:

- [How to Use Buffers in Node.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20160401013413/http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers)

Comment: What I mean is: var buf0=new Buffer ('牛');
Res.download (allpath,buf0.toString ('utf-8')) is not normal (in the browser, garbled.) and
Var buf0=new Buffer (' 牛');
res.download(allpath,buf0.toString('binary) ) is normal.but why?what change utf-8 to binary?

Comment: Can you provide a bunch of code with meaningful errors please? I'm not sure if I've understood your real problem.